# AutoHotkey ImageSearch not detecting image

Tags: automation, windows-10, autohotkey

I'm trying to make a bot with AutoHotkey to play a game called [BTD6](https://google.com/search?q=btd6) for me.

The problem is that I need to detect when the victory screen appears, and click a button. So I tried using `ImageSearch` to search for the button inside a `While` loop, but the loop never ends.

I made the test script bellow and it works fine:

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.


^b::
ImageSearch, ix, iy, 0, 0, A_ScreenWidth, A_ScreenHeight, next.png
Click, %ix% %iy%
Return


Escape::
ExitApp
Return
```

But when I put it in the main bot code, it does not work, I think it's because the loop never exits:

(scroll to the bottom of the code)

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
#Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.


CoordMode Pixel


^b::
While true {
    Click, 1223 1553
    Sleep, 1000
    Click, 2581 693
    Sleep, 100
    Click, 2581 693
    Sleep, 100
    Click, 2581 693
    Sleep, 100
    Click, 2581 693
    Sleep, 100
    Click, 2581 693
    Sleep, 100
    Click, 2581 693
    Sleep, 100
    Click, 2581 693
    Sleep, 100
    Click, 2581 693
    Sleep, 100
    Click, 2581 693
    Sleep, 100
    Click, 2581 693
    Sleep, 100
    Click, 801 1097
    Sleep, 1000
    Click, 882 668
    Sleep, 1000
    Click, 1994 720
    Sleep, 5000
    Click, 1444 1265,
    Sleep, 1000
    Send {k down}{k up}
    MouseMove, 2381, 1100, 20
    Sleep, 100
    Click
    Sleep, 1000
    Click
    Sleep, 1000
    Send {, down}{, up}
    Sleep, 100
    Send {, down}{, up}
    Sleep, 100
    Send {/ down}{/ up}
    Sleep, 100
    Send {/ down}{/ up}
    Sleep, 1000
    Click, 1453 816
    Sleep, 1000
    Send {z down}{z up}
    MouseMove, 2281, 971, 20
    Sleep, 100
    Click
    Sleep, 1000
    Click
    Sleep, 1000
    Send {. down}{. up}
    Sleep 100
    Send {. down}{. up}
    Sleep 100
    Send {/ down}{/ up}
    Sleep 100
    Send {/ down}{/ up}
    Sleep 100
    Send {/ down}{/ up}
    Sleep 100
    Send {/ down}{/ up}
    Sleep 100
    Click, 1453 816
    Sleep, 1000
    Send {f down}{f up}
    MouseMove, 2397, 967, 20,
    Sleep, 100
    Click
    Sleep, 1000
    Click
    Sleep, 1000
    Send {, down}{, up}
    Sleep 100
    Send {, down}{, up}
    Sleep 100
    Send {, down}{, up}
    Sleep 100
    Send {, down}{, up}
    Sleep 100
    Send {. down}{. up}
    Sleep 100
    Send {. down}{. up}
    Sleep 100
    Click, 1453 816
    Sleep, 1000
    Send {Space down}{Space up}
    Sleep, 1000
    While true {
        ImageSearch, foundx, foundy, 0, 0, A_ScreenWidth, A_ScreenHeight, next.png
        if (foundx or foundy) {
            Break
        } else {
            Sleep, 2000
        }
    }
    Click, %foundx% %foundy%
    foundx := 0
    foundy := 0
    Sleep, 1000
    Click, 1002 1419
    Sleep, 5000
}
Return

    
Escape::
ExitApp
Return
```

Comment: You want to use a timer. See [`SetTimer`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm).

Comment: I 2nd that. Something to bear in mind is the button may not actually be active at the extreme top left edge where you are having it click. Just a thought from using ImageSearch to automate a Java application pretty extensively.

Comment: The problem is that after having the code run for some time, it freezes and it doesn't do anything. Sometimes it runs one iteration and sometimes two, but never more than that, and it should loop forever

Answer (score 0):

OK so I used your code with SetTimer instead of trying to use a continuous loop. It *should* create the same effect as a continuous loop.

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
#Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.


CoordMode, Pixel

^b::
SetTimer, PlayGame, -10
Return

PlayGame:
Click, 1223 1553
Sleep, 1000
Click, 2581 693
Sleep, 100
Click, 2581 693
Sleep, 100
Click, 2581 693
Sleep, 100
Click, 2581 693
Sleep, 100
Click, 2581 693
Sleep, 100
Click, 2581 693
Sleep, 100
Click, 2581 693
Sleep, 100
Click, 2581 693
Sleep, 100
Click, 2581 693
Sleep, 100
Click, 2581 693
Sleep, 100
Click, 801 1097
Sleep, 1000
Click, 882 668
Sleep, 1000
Click, 1994 720
Sleep, 5000
Click, 1444 1265,
Sleep, 1000
Send {k down}{k up}
MouseMove, 2381, 1100, 20
Sleep, 100
Click
Sleep, 1000
Click
Sleep, 1000
Send {, down}{, up}
Sleep, 100
Send {, down}{, up}
Sleep, 100
Send {/ down}{/ up}
Sleep, 100
Send {/ down}{/ up}
Sleep, 1000
Click, 1453 816
Sleep, 1000
Send {z down}{z up}
MouseMove, 2281, 971, 20
Sleep, 100
Click
Sleep, 1000
Click
Sleep, 1000
Send {. down}{. up}
Sleep 100
Send {. down}{. up}
Sleep 100
Send {/ down}{/ up}
Sleep 100
Send {/ down}{/ up}
Sleep 100
Send {/ down}{/ up}
Sleep 100
Send {/ down}{/ up}
Sleep 100
Click, 1453 816
Sleep, 1000
Send {f down}{f up}
MouseMove, 2397, 967, 20,
Sleep, 100
Click
Sleep, 1000
Click
Sleep, 1000
Send {, down}{, up}
Sleep 100
Send {, down}{, up}
Sleep 100
Send {, down}{, up}
Sleep 100
Send {, down}{, up}
Sleep 100
Send {. down}{. up}
Sleep 100
Send {. down}{. up}
Sleep 100
Click, 1453 816
Sleep, 1000
Send {Space down}{Space up}
Sleep, 1000
Loop {
    ImageSearch, foundx, foundy, 0, 0, A_ScreenWidth, A_ScreenHeight, next.png
    if (ErrorLevel==0) {
        Break
    } ; else not needed because of Break above
    Sleep, 2000
}
Click, %foundx% %foundy%
foundy := foundx := 0
Sleep, 1000
Click, 1002 1419
Sleep, 5000
setTimer, %A_ThisLabel%, -10
Return

    
Escape::
ExitApp
Return
```

Although I never script games myself, there are better ways to do this, but I'll let you figure that out as you learn more of the language.